# can't update and create using datepicker in jquery and jtable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, jquery-jtable

I have got problems with date field. When I create a new record or update an existing one, the date field is saved as 000-00-00.

With the datepicker when I select any day ,It is stored in table with value (0000-00-00).

The DB field is date type.

I download the PHP sample code, create a DB with example sql and change the RecordDate field editable and I have the same problem.

DB value: 0000-00-00
JTable shows: 1899-11-30
What should I do?? Please help This is the jquery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {


   var assignmentid= "<?php echo $assignmentid; ?>";
        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'teacherfill.php?action=list&aid="<?php echo $assignmentid; ?>"',
                createAction: 'teacherfill.php?action=create&aid="<?php echo $assignmentid; ?>"',
                updateAction: 'teacherfill.php?action=update&aid="<?php echo $assignmentid; ?>"',
                deleteAction: 'teacherfill.php?action=delete&aid="<?php echo $assignmentid; ?>"'
            },
            fields: {
                lecture_id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                lecture_no: {
                    title: 'Lecture No',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                lecture_date: {
                    title: 'Lecture Date',
                    width: '20%',
                    type:'date'
                }

            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

    });
```

PHP Code:-

```
if($_GET["action"] == "update" && $_GET["aid"])
{

$assignmentid=$_GET['aid'];
    $updatedlecno=$_POST["lecture_no"];
    //$updatedlecdate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['lecture_date']));
$updatedlecdate=$_POST['lecture_date'];
    $lecid=$_POST["lecture_id"];
    $q="UPDATE lecture_schedule SET lecture_no=$updatedlecno,lecture_date=$updatedlecdate WHERE (lecture_id=$lecid)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
    if($result)
    {
        $er="No error";
    }
else{
    $er1=mysqli_error($conn);
    $er="error";

}
    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    //$jTableResult['status'] = $er;
    //$jTableResult['date'] = $updatedlecdate;




    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Comment: what is the format of your datepicker? `m/d/Y` or `Y-m-d`, probably its not correct.  The db accepts this format `Y-m-d`  You'll want to convert it with `DateTime` and `$DateTime->format('Y-m-d')` http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so, as per my comment on the date format.

```
  $DateTime = new DateTime($_POST['lecture_date']);
  $lecture_date = $DateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

You have to convert it from `m/d/Y` to the `Y-m-d` that the database uses ( ISO 8601 )

Comment: I have tried changing the format of date in php just like you suggested in the format 'Y-m-d' but it still doesn't work and also, the datepicker has the same format of date.

Comment: What do you mean the same format of date, specifically.

Comment: you have sql injection venerability, you may need to quote the date in the query  `lecture_date="$updatedlecdate"` its not an integer after all.  However I would use PDO and a placeholder  `lecture_date=:updatedlecdate`

Comment: echo the query, before executing the update and see if the value is what you expect, then try it in phpmyadmin

Comment: if you see the line which is commented in my php code..

//$updatedlecdate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['lecture_date']));

I have tried this thing and then used in query.

Comment: right but is your date quoted?  `UPDATE .... lecture_date=2016-7-30 WHERE ... ` OR `UPDATE .... lecture_date="2016-7-30" WHERE ... `

Comment: What if I put `0; DROP table lecture_schedule; --` in your `$_POST["lecture_no"]` variable, I just wiped out your DB, at least do `intval()` on the integers, and yes it is that easy to wipe out that table.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was trying this since 2 days and like you said quotes worked!!! Thanks a ton dude!!!  

Comment: Sure, be very weary of sql Injection.  It is real, and it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

check the date format of datepicker, if format is "d-m-Y" or "m-d-Y" or "d/m/Y" etc, you have to change it to "Y-m-d" format after form post in your php code, before insert/update.